# Am I going to lose Data if I take Transaction-Log backup and truncate log file?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have a database with an LDF file of around 14GB and an MDF file of 12GB.

No one has ever performed a Transaction log backup for this DB.

Though the team always just perform **Full DB Backup** every morning.

Resulting in the log file size is just growing and growing.

Now, If I take its transaction log backup and truncate log file.

Am I going to lose any data?

I am curious because taking log backup reduces log file size, I just want to make sure that their won't be any impact of my MDF file or Data that we have in DB.

And after taking t-log backup whats the good strategy?

Should we restore it to check if it works fine?

If I restore a t-log backup, is it mandatory to apply **Full Backup** restore first on that Testing server?

[SQL Server 2012]

Comment: Your "team" needs to have a serious discussion about disaster recovery and roles/responsibilities. If the full recovery model is appropriate, then your group needs to make a plan for implementing it correctly and ensuring the appropriate actions are taken on the planned basis.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "you wouldn't lose any more than what you normally would otherwise". However, there are several circumstances that might affect your final decision.

The first question your team should ask itself is, of course, "if we never take log backups, why the database is in the full recovery mode"? For DEV databases, log backups are unnecessary in most cases, so switch it to `SIMPLE` recovery, issue a `checkpoint` and then you can truncate the log. Oh, and it shouldn't grow much after that, unless someone would run a large modification batch in a single transaction.

Just make sure you [understand the difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql) between the truncation modes. Most probably, you will need to utilise both NOTRUNCATE and TRUNCATEONLY.

Whether you should start taking log backups regularly depends on your workflow and the importance of the data. The main benefits of the full recovery mode are:

1. In case of a disaster, you don't lose modifications made after the last full / diff backup, only after the last transaction log backup (which are usually short if taken regularly, and as such put less strain on a server). However, if your transaction log file survived the crash and you were able to perform a [tail-log backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server) after the database became unusable, you lose *nothing*.
2. You can perform a point-in-time restore of your database, which sometimes is a crucial capability - for example, when you investigate a data corruption / loss, or for any other investigation of that kind. However, as I've said, development databases are rarely that precious.

So weigh these options, consider your specifics, and the answer will come. If it doesn't, I recommend turning your attention to dba.stackexchange.com, as the question in its current form isn't really about development.

Answer (score 0):

your database recovery model is `full`  that means `sql` don't over write into `ldf` data pages until you get log backup , and then over write them
after that your log don't get larger unless you have a huge transaction
so , you may declare some log backup job or change recovery model to simple
and of course the full recovery model is better but remember you should keep every single log backup that you take after last full backup